# Crop and resize millions of photos

Tags: image-processing, image-resizing, batch-processing

I need to automate the task of resizing millions of photos.

The images need 20px cropped off the top and bottom before resizing.

When they are resized down to 200x200 they need to be chopped to a square thumbnail format  (this would involve cropping the top or sides of the photo to make the photo square)

I am using windows OS and it is imperative that the directory structure be preserved.

The original files are in JPG format.

My idea is to:

1) Copy all the photos that need resizing to a new SSD drive (preserving directory structure)

2) Crop 20px of the top and bottom

3) Resize and turn into thumbnails of 200x200

4) Save the files as JPEG

5) Rename all the files

6) Copy the files back to the original locations

I have been looking at photoshop automation to crop and resize the photos but it is not suitable for this task.

There are some other batch processing programs, but I need to crop before resize and preserve the dir structure.

We are looking at writing a program to do this ourselves, but just wondering is anybody knows of a command line tool that can do this - especially one that preserves dir structure?

Comment: It may help a bit :
http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27137/what-program-can-automatically-resize-crop-a-folder-of-images-to-a-certain-res

Answer (score 0):

Found ImageMagick that seems to be able to do what i want.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

Now have to figure out how to use it!